# Many to many getting "is invalid" error in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to do a many-to-many relation but I get `:roles=>[{:error=>:invalid}]` when trying to save.

Models

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_roles, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :roles, through: :user_roles
end

class Role < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :children, :class_name => "Admin::Role", foreign_key: "parent_id"
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "Admin::Role"
  has_many :user_roles, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :user_roles
end

class Admin::UserRole < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role
end
```

Controller

```
def new
  @user = User.new
end

def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      redirect_to users_url
    end
  end
end

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:role_ids => [])
end
```

_form.html.erb

```
form_with(model: user) do |form|
    form.collection_select(:role_ids, Roles.all, :id, :title, multiple: "multiple")
end
```

Params log

```
"user"=>{"role_ids"=>["", "1"]}
```

Comment: If roles is invalid, I would suggest you get the roles from the model and call valid? on all of them and see the actual full error on the invalid ones.

Comment: The code sounds good. Can you try it in console? `User.create(role_ids: ["", "1"])`. Also add the full error containing `:roles=>[{:error=>:invalid}]`

Comment: @arieljuod by searching through the errors I noticed that the invalid error was causing because the whatever role that has parent_id null. I fixed it by adding `optional: true` in `belongs_to :parent`

Comment: @iGian My issue is that I have a parent_id in roles that associates to itself and when I have a parent_id that is null I was getting the invalid error. I fixed it by adding `optional: true` in `belongs_to :parent`

Comment: It is not a bug, it is a feature in Rails, see https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/5402. 

> include_hidden: false

See also this change https://github.com/nashby/rails/commit/54a75e1a0f1c2369a9a4b2872c2213d32a8bc117:

> *   Add `include_hidden` option to select tag. With `:include_hidden => true` select with `multiple` attribute doesn't generate hidden input with blank value. *Vasiliy Ermolovich*